# Silverlight SaveFileDialog.SelectedFile?

Tags: c#, silverlight, savefiledialog

I'm working in Silverlight on an Exception handling dialog. When an exception is thrown, the dialog pops up with details about the error, and a button that allows the user to save the error log and send it to the developer. When the user clicks the `Save Error Log` button, a `SaveFileDialog` pops up and lets the user browse to where (s)he wants to save the file.

How do I get the full path (e.g. `C:\Folder\logfile.log`) of the selected file? The `SafeFileName` property only gives me the file name (e.g. `logfile.log`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the full path within an SL application due to being sandboxed. You could do this however within WPF since you have full access at that point.

That does not mean you can not save the file to the given location via the exposed `Stream` though. Complete example [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx).

```
            try 
            {  
                byte[] fileBytes = e.Result as byte[];  

                using ( Stream fs = (Stream)this.dialog.OpenFile() )  
                {  
                    fs.Write( fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length );  
                    fs.Close();  

                    this.tblError.Text = "File successfully saved!";  
                }  
            }  
            catch ( Exception ex )  
            {  
                this.tblError.Text = "Error getting result: " + ex.Message;  
            }
```